# send_keys Without Any Xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I have a [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGgJn.png) that I want to log into using Python's Selenium. But I can't get an xpath or something like that.

So, how do I log in? I already tried:

```
DRIVER.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys('test')
```

and

```
actions = ActionChains(DRIVER)
actions.send_keys('test')
actions.perform()
```

but both are not working.

Comment: Website (Please use Chrome): http://webtrash.musictunnel8080.de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HTTP authentication not a login web page.

Use something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
url = f'http://{username}:{password}@webtrash.musictunnel8080.de/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features="BlockCredentialedSubresources"')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

**Update**

Use `requests` package:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
url = 'http://webtrash.musictunnel8080.de/'
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
```

Comment: I think I got the reason why it's not working: Sending username and password as part of url like https://username:password@www.mytestsite.com may be helpful if same server performs both authentication and hosts the application. However most corporate applications have firmwide authentications and app server may reroute the request to authentication servers. In such cases, passing credentials in URL wont work.